# Combining Two SELECT Queries Connecting Three Tables and Taking Top 1 of Intermediate Table

Tags: sql

I have  3 tables `invoice_hd`, `invoice_dt`, `Account_Mast`. I want to join `invoice_hd` with `invoice_dt` using the condition `invoice_hd.ID=invoice_dt.INVOICE_ID` to get `AccountCode` from `Account_Mast` table.

But before joining the table `invoice_dt` to `Account_Mast`, I want to take `top 1` of `invoice_dt` as its result data contains more than one records. For that I created 2 select queries below:

```
select IH.ID,
IH.CODE,
IH.DATE,
C.CCODE      
FROM invoice_hd IH 
LEFT JOIN Currencies C ON C.ID = IH.CURRENCY_ID 
WHERE APPROVAL_FLAG='FL' and IH.code = 'LI/15'


SELECT TOP 1 SID.ID,SID.INVOICE_ID,AM.CODE AS ACCOUNT_CODE 
FROM invoice_dt SID
LEFT JOIN Account_Mast AM ON BAM.ID = SID.ACCOUNT_ID 
WHERE SID.INVOICE_ID = 1028
```

Now I want to combine these two select queries with the condition`invoice_hd.ID=invoice_dt.INVOICE_ID`. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: What is the `Top 1` based on? or are you taking any random detail line?

Comment: Resulting records having identical columns instead of ID column. Thats why i am taking top 1 of records to get atleast one row.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `TOP` is non-standard SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are saying that the detail line doesn't matter (which is odd), then you can just do this:

```
SELECT IH.ID, IH.CODE, IH.DATE, C.CCODE, AM.CODE AS ACCOUNT_CODE      
FROM invoice_hd IH 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT INVOICE_ID, MAX(ACCOUNT_ID) AS ACCOUNT_ID 
    FROM invoice_dt 
    GROUP BY INVOICE_ID) AS DT ON invoice_hd.ID = DT.INVOICE_ID
LEFT JOIN Account_Mast AM ON AM.ID = dt.ACCOUNT_ID 
LEFT JOIN Currencies C ON C.ID = IH.CURRENCY_ID 
WHERE APPROVAL_FLAG='FL' 
AND IH.code = 'LI/15'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use both query as subquery and join it like tables, for example:

```
SELECT
    /* It's better if you avoid use * in the select */
    A.ID,
    A.CODE,
    A.DATE,
    A.CCODE,
    B.ID,
    B.INVOICE_ID,
    B.ACCOUNT_CODE
FROM (
    /* Here your first query */
    SELECT
        IH.ID,
        IH.CODE,
        IH.DATE,
        C.CCODE
    FROM invoice_hd IH 
    LEFT JOIN Currencies C ON C.ID = IH.CURRENCY_ID 
    WHERE APPROVAL_FLAG='FL' and IH.code = 'LI/15'
) AS A
INNER JOIN (
    /* Then your second one */
    SELECT TOP 1
        SID.ID,
        SID.INVOICE_ID,
        AM.CODE AS ACCOUNT_CODE 
    FROM invoice_dt SID
    LEFT JOIN Account_Mast AM ON BAM.ID = SID.ACCOUNT_ID 
    WHERE SID.INVOICE_ID = 1028
) AS B
/* And for last your condition of join */
ON A.ID = B.INVOICE_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea on how you can achieve this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
   (select * from table1) q1 LEFT JOIN 
   (select * from table2) q2 on q1.id=q2.id
```